# ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. latex

Tags: latex

hey, I met these latex format problem, anyone can offer some help?

the .tex file:

```
  \begin{table}{}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \caption{Cambridge Flow feature definition and description}
  \label{cambridge-feature}}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline\bfseries Abbreviation &\bfseries Description\\
  \hline
  serv-port & Server port\\
  \hline
  clnt-port & Client port\\
  \hline
  push-pkts-serv & count of all packets with\\ 
   & push bit set in TCP header (server to client)\\
  \hline
  init-win-bytes-clnt & the total number of bytes \\
  & sent in initial window (client to server)\\
  \hline
  init-win-bytes-serv & the total number of bytes sent\\
  & in initial window (server to client)\\
  \hline
  avg-seg-size-clnt & average segment size: \\
  & data bytes devided by number of packets\\
  \hline
  IP-bytes-med-clnt & median of total bytes in IP packet\\
  \hline
  act-data-pkt-serv & count of packet with at least one byte \\
  & of TCP data playload (server to client)\\
  \hline
  data-bytes-var-clnt & variance of total \\
  & bytes in packets (client to server)\\
  \hline
  min-seg-size-serv & minimum segment size \\
  & observed (server to client)\\
  \hline
  RTT-samples-serv & total number of RTT samples\\
  & found (server to client),\\
  & {\bf see also \cite{Moore05discriminators}}\\
  \hline
  push-pkts-clnt &  count of all packets with push bit set \\
  & in TCP header (server to client)\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

and the error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup
\color@endbox
l.892 \end{table}
```

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in`\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

there is no $ in my table, also this { are matching with the }, and also after I comment the citation, the error remains.

anyone can offer help?

really appreciate all the comments!

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

Comment: Please format your code. People aren't likely to help out if you just post a wall of text.

Answer (score 14):

This line:

```
  \label{cambridge-feature}}
```

has an extra right brace.